# How scroll a fragment horizontally in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a detail view Fragment which I want to scroll Horizontally as well as Vertically.
Below is the fragment layout .xml where I have made use of ScrollView :-

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >


<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.ui.DragLayer
        android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.ui.DragLayer>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editor_btn"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drag_layer"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_white"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/editor_text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Using this I am able to scroll only vertically.Can anyone please help me out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scroll the same ScrollView both horizontally and vertically. You can only do one of these. The default is vertical scrolling.

Comment: indeed. It's also against every the User Experience rules.